# Internet Explorer 8 compatibility issues

Tags: internet-explorer-8

My website is developed in IE6 environment, and it is working fine. On one of our users' pc we have IE8. Here some of the controls are overlapping with other controls, and Infragistics grid is not displaying properly.

In my HTTP Header I added `X-UA-Compatible`, and in the value column `IE=EmulateIE8`, but this does not fulfill my requirement.

In webconfig i added the following code:

```
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
           <httpProtocol> 
               <customHeaders> 
                    <clear /> 
                    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE8" /> 
               </customHeaders> 
           </httpProtocol> 
     </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

I got the following error message while compiling:

> "more than one configuration
>   section..not allowed.."

or something like that.

in the html portion i added after `<head>` tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

This also not working properly...

Please advise me, I am a beginner in ASP.net 2.0.

Comment: DON'T PUT YOUR TITLES IN ALL CAPS PLEASE.

Comment: I have edited the title.

Comment: Maybe this question is more appropriate for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3):

See this : [Understanding Compatibility Modes in Internet Explorer 8](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askie/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8?wa=wsignin1.0).

Without knowing much about your html, I can still remark that you should probably use EmulateIE7 (not EmulateIE8) and set your DOCTYPE to Quirks Mode.

See this : [Quirks Mode - Using the DOCTYPE Tag](https://www.lifewire.com/using-doctype-element-3464264).